# Why <Element> is not needed when creating default value array in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

The code below is excerpted from *The Swift Programming Language (Swift 4.2)* of Apple documentation.

Now consider this: there are 3 ways to create an empty array in Swift.

First:

`var list1 = Array<String>()`

Second:

`var list2: [String] = []`

Third:

`var list3 = [String]()`

In order to create a default value array, we make use of `repeating:` and `count:`

`var list4 = Array(repeating: "Apples", count: 3)`

The above array is created using the first form of array creation, however, why it is not needed to declare the `<Element>` next to `Array` initializer.

Trying to create a normal empty array without specifying which type inside the `<Element>` would trigger a runtime error.

`var list5 = Array("Apples")` //A,p,p,l,e,s

`var list6 = Array("Apples", "Oranges")` //return an error

Why this happens?

Comment: Note: The third way is the same as the first. `[String]` is syntactic sugar for `Array<String>` and `[String]` is actually the preferred syntax.

Comment: `var list7: [String] = Array()` works to create an empty array because you've already told Swift it is an array of `String`, although you'd use the second method above instead.

Comment: A neat trick for understanding which initializer you are calling is to add `.init` and then *option*-click on `init`.  If you do that with `var list5 = Array.init("Apples")` you will find that the initializer used takes a sequence of characters and creates an Array of characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it knows the type of the first item. Since Arrays only contain objects of a single type, of it can get that information from the first item, then it is enough.

Following your comment:
 I think you are getting confused with the first item. "Oranges" is an array of `[Character]` so when you use `Array("Oranges")` you are creating an array of characters. For your third item, rather than passing in two values, which an Array doesn't know how to deal with, pass in an array like this: `let list6 = Array(["Apples", "Oranges"])`

Comment: Then why would this triggers an error `var list5 = Array("Apples", "Oranges")`

Comment: Because there isn’t an initialiser for an array that takes two items

Comment: @Slick For that case you would typically say `var list5 =["Apples","Oranges"]`